# Build dynamic windows library (DLL) from libmcrypt with MinGW

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, makefile, mingw

I'm trying to build libmcrypt library to use it with my project. It happened so, that they do not provide any kind of assistance.

First I've faced a problem with *-no-undefined* flag for gcc which is not further supported. I've replaced `-no-undefined` with `-Wl,-no-undefined` in makefiles and it does the trick.

But anyway I'am having problems. Lib is builded in .a files. I can see them in my C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib folder (it is analogue for /usr/local/lib folder in MinGW). But I need .dll library, not static .a .

So: what else must I change in makefiles to make MinGW build dll with header and debug info for it?

Comment: No one can possibly answer this effectively, unless you *show* us the fragments of your makefiles which specify how you are trying to link the DLL.

Comment: Unless you are trying to build libmcrypt.dll as an MSYS DLL, (which I hope you are not), C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\lib is most definitely **not** an analogue for /usr/local/lib in MinGW! It is reserved for use by those who develop MSYS itself; please do not misuse it for anything else.

Comment: @KeithMarshall , actually I don't know the difference between MSYS DLL and usual Windows DLL. All I want is to make this library work somehow on win32 systems and have header and debug symbols for it ir to work with it within my app. As soon as sources of this library doesn't contain any of windows IDE projects I am trying to build it with MinGW.


I thought it is analogue because /usr/ for sh.exe from MinGW is mapped there. Maybe I **am** mistaking.

Comment: @KeithMarshall , by "_mapped there_" I meant that `make` without specifying `--prefix` and `--exec-prefix` is building library in that folder. Nothing else.

Comment: The difference between MSYS and regular MinGW DLLs is that an MSYS DLL becomes part of MSYS itself; it depends on msys-1.0.dll, and cannot be deployed on any system on which MSYS is not installed. A MinGW DLL is not so constrained.

Comment: You should **never** configure a MinGW build without specifying `--prefix`, (unless the project has been specifically designed as a MinGW project, and specifies a more appropriate default than `/usr/local`). If you intend the result to become part of your MinGW tool chain, then `--prefix=C:/MinGW`, (if that is where your MinGW tools are installed), is usually a reasonable choice.